# Expert Marksman Score

Tags: americas-army-3

What score do I need for Expert on Squad Designated Marksman training

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hitting between the eyes 37 out of 40 times will net you a score of 1155/1200, which is enough for Expert ranking.

Comment: 37*30 is only 1110. The 3 non-head shots need to be body hits, right?

Comment: @antony: Correct.